# How can i get Ansible to wait until a service is active?

Tags: ansible

I can check if a service is started(as below), but how do i use the service facts in Ansible to loop\wait until a service is active?

```
  - name: Ensure myservice is in a running state
    service:
      name: myservice 
      state: started
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is very similar to @zigarn answer above, In my case it was not enough to know that the service was started or running, i needed to know it was active, hence im posting what i went with.
Thank you to all for your help

```
- name: Ensure myservice  is in a running state
    service:
      name: myservice 
      state: started
    register: myserviceDetails
    until: myserviceDetails.status.ActiveState == "active"
    retries: 15
    delay: 20
```

Comment: [*wait_for*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/wait_for_module.html) [*state=drained*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/wait_for_module.html#parameter-state) will also *"check for active connections"* and you don't have to care about *register/until*.

Answer (score 3):

Use the module [*wait_for*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/wait_for_module.html#wait-for-waits-for-a-condition-before-continuing). For example, if the service is a web server

```yaml
  - wait_for:
      port: 80
```

The default [*state*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/wait_for_module.html#parameter-state) is *started*. If you want to wait for the active connection set *`state: drained`*

```yaml
  - wait_for:
      port: 80
      state: drained
```

See the parameter [*active_connection_states*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/wait_for_module.html#parameter-active_connection_states).

Answer (score 3):

For a generic solution with any type of service, the solution would be to loop on getting service status until it's 'running'.

To achieve that, you can use the [`service_facts`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/service_facts_module.html) module with an [`until` loop](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#retrying-a-task-until-a-condition-is-met):

```yaml
- name: Wait for service 'myservice' to be running
  service_facts:
  register: result
  until: result.ansible_facts.services['some.service'].state == 'running'
  retries: 10
  delay: 5
```